# Web API get route values

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Is there any way to statically get route values from a service method (outside of a controller) that is running in a Web API context? For example, I can do the following in ASP.NET MVC:

```
var mvcHandler = HttpContext.Current.Handler as MvcHandler;
var routeValues = mvcHandler.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
```

I'd like to find the equivalent version of this code for Web API.

When I try to debug a sample Web API request and look at `HttpContext.Current.Handler` it is of type `HttpControllerHandler`, but this type doesn't have any properties to access route data.

**EDIT**

To try to help provide some more information. The code I am trying to read the value from is inside of a factory class I have that builds a custom object for my application.

Comment: Kyle, would you please post the Web API version of the code for us?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out :)

Comment: Do you mean you did 'using System.Web.Http; var handler = Http.Current.Handler' and found it to be HttpControllerHandler?

Comment: Yes, that's what I found.

Comment: Have you tried the `Routes` property on `HttpConfiguration` object or is that also not the right context

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to find a solution that would get the route values for either an MVC request or a Web API request.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use GetRouteData() extension on HttpRequestMessage. You would need to include System.Net.Http namespace to get this.

```
System.Web.Http.Routing.IHttpRouteData routeData = Request.GetRouteData();
```

Comment: Thanks. It appears this would work within a controller, but outside of a controller HttpContext.Current.Request isn't of type HttpRequestMessage (and can't be cast to it). I should have clarified this better in the OP.

Comment: No, you would be able to access it anywhere you have access to HttpRequestMessage. Example inside message handler: 'public class DelegateHandlerA : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            System.Web.Http.Routing.IHttpRouteData routeData = request.GetRouteData();
            
            HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            return response;
        }
    }'

Comment: BTW, GetRouteData() extension would give a consistent experience across WebHost(IIS) and SelfHost(where HttpContext is not available) scenarios too.

Comment: @PeteKlein No, I wasn't able to. My factory classes don't have access to the HttpRequestMessage. I agree this is a cleaner approach than what I suggested, but I haven't been able to get it to work the way I want.

Comment: Would you please explain a bit about why you are not avoiding the use of an ApiController?

Comment: @KiranChalla I was trying to use your solution, to use the extension method, but I get null. I am running self host for development but will use IIS, and I am trying to get the route template in the context of a DelegatingHandler. It did not work for either so I wonder if yourself got this working.

Comment: Hello @KiranChalla, Thank you very much! this does exactly what I was looking for. I am passing a request to an API in the form of a route value such as `http//somehost/controller/action/acode/aname/adate/anotherdate` and the method you suggested returned a nicely packaged dictionary response with all of the elements after the action value. Thank you.